# CoreData Issue: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My CoreData Worked before when I had an entity with one attribute called test, I tried to add a new attribute in the data model and I also defined it in my data.swift file but when I launch the application, it crashes on the loading screen every time, what am I not doing right? I can provide my code as needed.

Comment: what is error showing , show here

Comment: Show the crash.  Show any error messages.  If you are trying to run the app as an upgrade to an installed version, it may be a CoreData migration problem.  If it's a clean install, we're back to needing errors and stack trace for clues.

Comment: Sorry for not providing all of the errors, will be sure to next time. @Sport

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run the application and then change the CoreDataModel, the next time you run the application it will give you an error indicating that the data model used has changed. To fix this, you can either remove the old version from the simulator (or device) and run the app again, or you can [create a new CoreData version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html).

If just testing before the app has been released, deleting and running the app again works fine...

Comment: Wonderful answer, I couldn't find that anywhere. That's exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Comment: @c_rath Quick Question! will it crash on users who downloaded the updated version of the app (with new CoreDataModel) forcing them to uninstall the app and reinstall it? or will this issue be resolved through the app-Store?